# How to fix 'invalid syntax' from retro library in colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I'm trying to use google-colab for a project, but when I try to import retro (an openai library) with it, it sends me an invalid syntax error from the library.

I'm using the python 3 type of execution and I used !pip install retro to make sure it is installed. I tried getting into the file to fix the problem, but it seems I can't reach it.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/retro/__init__.py", line 206
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

This version of the library is not compatible with Python 3, only with Python 2.

You seem to have installed an old version; the current code is compatible. You should update the version.

Answer (score 1):

You're using python 2 syntax with python 3. The `print` keyword became a `print()` function:

```
>>> print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with parenthesis:

```
>>> key = 1; value = 2
>>> print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
1: 2
```

hope it helps